# How to connect python to wamp server

Tags: apache, python-3.x, wampserver

I am trying to learn web python programming and because of that i tried to install python in wamp server using the procedure given  in this [tutorial](http://martinprzybyla.com/2011/02/01/how-to-get-python-working-with-apache-and-wampserver-win-7/). I have gone through the steps as mentioned in tutorial.But When i tried to run the python script it is showing this error in firefox

```
      Unable to connect

      Firefox can't establish a connection to the server at localhost.
```

i have found out that addition of these two scripts in apache/httpd.conf some how affects the whole wamp server

```
1)LoadModule wsgi_module modules/mod_wsgi.so

and

2) <Directory “C:/wamp/www/python”>
   Options ExecCGI
    AddHandler wsgi-script .py
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
    </Directory>
```

When i enabled above code in all combinations (1,2 and both) and restarted;the server showed offline (yellow 'W' sign) but when i removed or disabled (using #) both scripts it showed green 'W' sign of wamp and it is working.

anyone have any idea why its showing this error and how i can i run python files in wamp?

my system configration

```
windows 7 32 bit
python 3.2
[mod_wsgi][2] for python 3.1
WampServer Version 2.1
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have a couple of problems here, since WAMP won't start with wsgi_module enabled. Let's start with the second problem, which is a duplicate of [this question](https://serverfault.com/questions/332570/wamp-server-not-working-when-i-add-a-directory-directive). Basically, the tutorial you are following seems to have a typo and some bad quotes. Change your virtual host configuration to say:

```
<Directory "C:/wamp/www/python">
   Options ExecCGI
    AddHandler wsgi-script.py
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

(Notice the straight quotes around your directory name and the space I removed from the AddHandler line)

Once you have fixed this, is your WAMP still staying yellow when you include the `LoadModule wsgi_module modules/mod_wsgi.so` line?

Comment: Is WAMP green now and the page is just showing 'Unable to connect', or is WAMP still yellow?

Comment: Is there anything in the apache error logs about this module (wsgi_module)? Perhaps it cannot find the file?